# Multiple rows of data into a single row - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks a little like this

```
ID          NAME          MODULE          STARTDATE          ENDDATE          MARK
123456      J Bloggs      Module 1        13/01/2014         30/04/2014       FAIL
123456      J Bloggs      Module 1        13/05/2014         30/08/2014       FAIL
123456      J Bloggs      Module 1        13/09/2014         30/12/2014       PASS
123456      J Bloggs      Module 2        13/05/2014         30/08/2014       PASS
123456      J Bloggs      Module 3        13/01/2015         30/04/2015       FAIL
234567      A Test        Module 1        13/01/2014         30/04/2014       PASS
234567      A Test        Module 2        13/05/2014         30/08/2014       FAIL
234567      A Test        Module 2        13/09/2014         30/12/2014       PASS
```

The table contains vast amounts of data, similar in structure to this. What I am trying to do is almost concatenate some of the data from multiple rows into a single row structure based on the student and the module taken, so the end result would look something like

```
ID          NAME          MODULE          ENDDATE1          ENDDATE2          ENDDATE3          MARK
123456      J Bloggs      Module 1        30/04/2014        30/08/2014        30/12/2014        PASS
123456      J Bloggs      Module 2        30/08/2014                                            PASS
123456      J Bloggs      Module 3        30/04/2015                                            FAIL
234567      A Test        Module 1        30/04/2014                                            PASS
234567      A Test        Module 2        30/08/2014        30/12/2014                          PASS
```

So the new table would display all the end dates on the same row based on the module, and then the most recent mark 'max(Mark)' would be displayed. There are likely to be more than 3 possible End Dates as is displayed in the example table as this will depend entirely on the original table and how many times a student may have had to 'resit' a module (could be up to 4/5 times in some cases).

Comment: Will there only be a maximum of 3 end dates or could there be more?

Comment: I suggest that you work with the last 3 dates, and maybe add another column to state the amount of other tries there where except for the 3 that are displayed. You otherwise have to many possibilities because I student can fail over and over again. Or display only the last result, Mark, and count of other tries, because the other tries will all be fail anyway. And then you can drill through if you want specific test data.

Comment: If you pick a maximum amount of dates we can work with that?

Comment: I would say it would be surprising to see more than 5 dates

Answer (score 0):

Try using Dynamic Pivot :

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table') IS NOT NULL)
DROP TABLE #TABLE
CREATE TABLE  #TABLE (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(30),MODULE VARCHAR(30),STARTDATE VARCHAR(30),ENDDATE VARCHAR(30),MARK VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO #TABLE VALUES
(123456, 'J Bloggs', 'Module 1', '13/01/2014', '30/04/2014', 'FAIL'),
(123456, 'J Bloggs', 'Module 1', '13/05/2014', '30/08/2014', 'FAIL'),
(123456, 'J Bloggs', 'Module 1', '13/09/2014', '30/12/2014', 'PASS'),
(123456, 'J Bloggs', 'Module 2', '13/05/2014', '30/08/2014', 'PASS'),
(123456, 'J Bloggs', 'Module 3', '13/01/2015', '30/04/2015', 'FAIL'),
(234567, 'A Test', 'Module 1', '13/01/2014', '30/04/2014', 'PASS'),
(234567, 'A Test', 'Module 2', '13/05/2014', '30/08/2014', 'FAIL'),
(234567, 'A Test', 'Module 2', '13/09/2014', '30/12/2014', 'PASS')
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns = STUFF((SELECT ',' + '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), number, 121) + ']'
                         FROM   master..spt_values N
                         WHERE  n.number BETWEEN 1 AND (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(Enddate)
                                                        FROM   #TABLE
                                                        GROUP  BY ID,NAME,MODULE
                                                        ORDER  BY COUNT(Enddate) DESC)
                                AND TYPE = 'P'
                         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT ID,
       NAME,
       MODULE,
       '+@Columns+',
       (SELECT TOP 1 MARK
        FROM   #table t1
        WHERE  pvt.ID = t1.ID
               AND pvt.NAME = t1.NAME
               AND pvt.MODULE = t1.MODULE
        ORDER  BY enddate DESC) AS MARK
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               NAME,
               MODULE,
               ENDDATE,
               ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER(
                   partition BY ID, NAME, MODULE
                   ORDER BY enddate) AS rn
        FROM   #table) t
       PIVOT ( Max(ENDDATE)
             FOR rn IN('+@Columns+')) AS pvt 
'

EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql
```

Check details of Pivot and Unpivot [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

NOTE : As you can see, I used a sub-query to find the latest `Mark`. I tried my best to replace it with something better but I couldn't. Still, it will work for you.